# Import Certificate and Private Key for Java

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am getting the following error from a Java Application
`ERROR: Naming service connection failed for https://*******
com.iplanet.services.comm.client.SendRequestException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:`

I have been provided two files from who managed the target URL:

File.cer (should be a DER Encoded certificate)
File.key (it's the private key)

I have then Read a lot from different site about what I need to do in order to import both into the JVM using tje keytool, ma still haven't understood how to do it correctly. Is there a procedure ?

Comment: Could you add command line you are using for this import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the certificate in your truststore with the following:

keytool -import -alias YOURALIAS -file  File.cer -keystore YOURTRUSTSTORE.truststore -password YOURTRUSTSTOREPASSWORD

In your JVM arguments, please make sure you have
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=
and
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword

Comment: I don't have any truststore. Can I use java default one ? And what the use of the "File.key" that they have provided me then ?

Comment: Normally it is not recommended to use cacerts file but try importing it in your cacerts and restart jvm. There is a default password for cacerts. Search google for it.